# Authentication Providers 'greyed out' in sharepoint 2010 (enable anonymous access)

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, config

I am trying to config a sharepoint 2010 site for anonymous access. The tutorials I am following are:

1. http://live.visitmix.com/Videos
2. http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-9-turn-on-anonymous.html
3. http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010

And a few youtube videos.

I am stuck fast in a certain point. When I am told in Central Admin to click **"Site Actions > Site Settings > Application Management > Manage Applications > SharePoint - 80"** I do this. My next step is to click **"Authentication Providers".**

In my system this option is 'Greyed out' and not selectable. I also try to click **"Anonymous Policy"**. The options in this section are also not selectable.

Is there further config needed? Can anyone suggest a possible solution? or link an article with the solution? The mix videos leave this config out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution:

I went a different way and basically opened every option related to security / perms / anon.

I ended up from central administration clicking **"Security > Specify Authentication Provider > Default"**

I was then able to allow anon access. The correct options have appeared to the site collection administrator.

Comment: I found myself in this same situation recently and I'm curious what causes it. In my case, I logged on as the local administartor on the box and the button was enabled. But I'm curious why my other user account can see the page you link to hear but has the button greyed out. Let me know if you ever found out more about this.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Internet Explorer.

I had the same problem when using Firefox 3.6.8, but not in IE 8.

Also don't forget to open Internet Explorer with elevated administrator privileges.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using Windows 8 ensure that the browser you're using for the update is running in admin mode.

Otherwise just open another instance by "Run as administrator".

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I logged on as the local administrator on the box and the button was enabled, but when I tried to save, it error'ed out.
I created a new web application, and successfully made it anon, and was then able to make the original one anon too - no more error.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest thing to verify: when opening up Central Administration in IE, ensure that you run it 'as administrator'

If you do, then no items like the authentication provider options on the ribbon will be disabled.